# UITextField return from UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios

How to resign a `UITextField` of `UISearchBar`? I tried with the below code

```
    UIView * subView;
    NSArray * subViews = [self.searchBar subviews];
    for(subView in subViews)
    {
        if( [subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] )
        {
            ((UITextField*)subView).delegate=self;
            ((UITextField*)subView).returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
        {
            [(UITextField *)subview setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
        }
    }
```

And added the TextField Delegate method

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

  return YES;
   }
```

this works but this resigns the keyboard oly if the textfield is not empty. If the textfield is empty then it is not resigning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I used this code when i select any row of my tableview to my scenario it worked I didnt had any problem with ipad but only with iphone i had this. All the others were also correct but you were the first to reply hence accepted yours thanks

Answer (score 0):

First set Delegate in .h file like bellow...

```
 @interface yourViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>
```

and when you want to resign keyboard of `UISearchBar` simple use bellow line..

```
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

**UPDATE:**

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I am doing that in -searchBarTextDidEndEditing but it is not resigning

Comment: instead of that method use this method.. -(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)tempsearchBar and resign here and also first check that you give delegate to self for searchBar??

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy first see add UISearchBarDelegate in your .h file and in viewDidLoad method set searchBar.delegate = self; and then try to resign it

Comment: I have added the delegates correctly the search functionality is working perfectly i have problem oly while resigning keyboard that too oly wen the searchbar doesnt have text

Comment: add this condition in your method at last. and return YES;... if ([theSearchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy see i update the code here may be problem is you return No in searchBarShouldEndEditing method when serachbar textfield have not any text may be... so try my code...

Comment: yes i did i tried all the answers and simply made a resignFirstResponder in two places where i need in searchBarShouldEndEditing the searchbar didnt resign

Answer (score 0):

Please do this one...

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchBar.text.length == 0)
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

i hope this will work fine.